# source code/docs for sun.misc.*

Tags: java

I came across the sum.misc.Unsafe class when reading the implementation of ForkJoinPool. But no source code or api docs were found in the JDK.

Where can I find the source code or api docs for the sun.misc.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Java source code, I usually go to [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/misc/Unsafe.java)

Comment: GrepCode is great, but how do I know that's the version that ships with my jdk/jre?

Answer (score 2):

While such code is available (see Binyamin's post) it is generally a very bad idea to write anything that *needs* such code.

First, you are not generally assured that any JVM has such a class available (only JVMs descending from SUN's codebase would contain non-published, non-standard, SUN specific libraries).  Also, since these are not standard libraries, you can't really depend on them being present or unchanged in subsequent releases of the SUN JVM.

Comment: +1 While I make use of these libraries in some of my libraries I a) make sure to also implement a version which doesn't require Unsafe b) can then check whether it really make a difference. c) use it as little as possible. It worth noting there is an intention to remove/change it significantly in future versions. e.g. Java 8+. Whether this actually happens is another question. ;)

Comment: While it is "best practice" not to use such libraries, it has not stopped the more determined from actually making good use of them - and usually for profit.  So attempting to deter the determined will only exacerbate their curiosity, so +1 for saying you shouldn't go there ;-) 

  If you're touching deep internals of any system, you always carry the risk that these implementations go away.  However, Unsafe is so intrinsic to many APIs and many JVMs, I very much doubt it will go away easily.