# Seeing source code of sun.misc which is part of rt.jar

Tags: java, rt.jar

I was checking `LockSupport.class` (from eclipse, which is part of `rt.jar`) and came to know this class internally uses `sun.misc.Unsafe` for its implementation.

In general, for **most of the packages** which are present in rt.jar, I can see the source, for example can see `LockSupport.class` , `String.class` (and see their code).

However, when I tried to see `sun.misc.Unsafe`, it didn't show anything. I see a similar question  on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442544/source-code-docs-for-sun-misc) - old question with same doubt. Of course , experts suggested to use `GrepCode`. However, my question is why can't we see the source when we can see for other packages in rt.jar?

In the same SO question, it was suggested not to rely upon `sun.misc.*`, but it is still widely used.

How can I see the exact code which is applicable for a specific JDK?

Comment: *"why can't we see the source when we can see for other packages in rt.jar?"* Because `sun.misc` classes are considered internal, and you shouldn't be using them.

Comment: Source code for `Unsafe`: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/43cb25339b55/src/share/classes/sun/misc/Unsafe.java

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks for your comment. But it is there since ages. My intention is to see the code and know a little more.

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks for providing the link. If the source is available freely, then why isn't is made part of rt.jar so that it can be seen like any other class?

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks for your reply. Got the jist of it.